# Unreal editor crash when changing multiple blueprints

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am working on a small game for a uni course and we are required to use blueprints. But unreal has started crashing when I edit them. Any solutions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. I will provide any info that might help. Thanks.

Crash message ->

```
Assertion failed: SourceObject [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\MetaData.cpp] [Line: 64]

UnrealEditor_CoreUObject
UnrealEditor_Engine
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject
UnrealEditor_Engine
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_Engine
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
kernel32
ntdll
```

I tried to edit a blueprint. And I was expecting to not crash consistently.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Install the debugging symbols for your engine version so in the future you can paste something more meaningful when having a crash. Just seeing the module name is usually not enough to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know that was a thing. I will ask the admin if I can install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was editing child actor templates. Which you are not allowed to do even though it lets you. I started creating child blueprints instead and that solved my problem.